# Biber no longer generates bbl file due to system crashing

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I was using TeXstudio and everything was good. My PC suddenly stopped working (complete hanging with no responses) due to motherboard failure.

After restarting, I noted that `biber` does not generate any `bbl` files and throws the following error in the messages

> Process started: biber Sorry, but biber did not succeed. The log file
> hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
> C:\Users\almot\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\biber.log Process
> exited with error(s)

The log file is

> 2022-10-24 13:55:11,356+0300 INFO  biber - this process (13340)
> started by texstudio in directory D:\Dropbox\Documents\Research
> writing\LaTeX\LaTeX Reference Guide\Important Scripts\biblatex\sorting
> with command line: biber 2022-10-24 13:55:11,357+0300 INFO  biber -
> running on Windows 10.0.19043 2022-10-24 13:55:11,365+0300 INFO
> biber.core - start process: biber 2022-10-24 13:55:11,436+0300 ERROR
> biber.core - The requested operation requires elevation.
>
> 2022-10-24 13:55:11,437+0300 ERROR biber.core - Function:
> CreateProcess 2022-10-24 13:55:11,437+0300 ERROR biber.core - Result:
> 740 2022-10-24 13:55:11,437+0300 ERROR biber.core - Data:
> commandLine="biber",
> fileName="C:\Users\almot\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\executables/windows-x64/biber\biber.exe"
> 2022-10-24 13:55:11,442+0300 ERROR biber.core - Source:
> Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp:309 2022-10-24
> 13:55:11,444+0300 FATAL biber - Windows API error 740: The requested
> operation requires elevation.
>
> 2022-10-24 13:55:11,444+0300 FATAL biber - Info: commandLine="biber",
> fileName="C:\Users\almot\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\executables/windows-x64/biber\biber.exe"
> 2022-10-24 13:55:11,444+0300 FATAL biber - Source:
> Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp 2022-10-24
> 13:55:11,444+0300 FATAL biber - Line: 309

I then discovered that `biber` fails in unpacking itself to

> C:\Users\almot\AppData\Local\Temp

All other programs are functioning normally including `bibtex`. This means it is not really about Windows API error 740

Is it possible to tell `biber` through the command prompt to remove all cache and auxiliary files to get fresh start?

```
% !TeX TXS-program:bibliography = biber

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document} 
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could try to deinstall and reinstall biber. But the error message could also mean that biber is trying to unpack in a location for which you are missing the rights. Check if the temp variable is correct.

Comment: What is the temp variable? biber unpacks itself to `C:\Users\almot\AppData\Local\Temp\par-4d6f746173656d\cache-7afc4fc5c8fa7926d81435d9c123258d56880b45`

Comment: One workaround is to open the editor as administrator, but this results in the message `pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges` which I want to remove